# Is there a good example of handling ServiceStack validation errors in an ASP.NET Core MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

The question is self explanatory.  Basically I want the api ton act as the service/business layer.  All logic should be handled here with validation errors and othe messages being returned back and handled inside the mvc controller.  With error messages getting mapped to the correct field on the ModelState for displaying to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think errors should be handled in Service layer. Since Service layer is a logic layer, exceptions should be thrown from there.
Then, you can catch thrown exceptions inside Mvc Controller and display like you want.

Moreover, logic exception handling will be the same from Mvc Controller and from other programs calling Service layer directly.